# Why does my SelfQueryRetriever (Langchain) return an empty response despite the prompt working?

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I've built a RAG using Langchain, specifically with the goal of using SelfQueryRetriever to filter based on metadata.  I've created a vector store using e5-large embeddings and stored it in a Chroma db.  I'm able to query the Chroma db using similarity search with no issues - the results are pretty good, actually.

The issue arises when I try to use a SelfQueryRetriever.  Reading through the debug log, I can see that the prompt is being created correctly, the metadata filters are working as I intended - but no documents are returned.  I've included the code below as well as the relevant portion of the debug log.  What's my issue here?

```
def make_embedder(model_name='intfloat/e5-large-v2',model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'}, encode_kwargs={'normalize_embeddings': False}):
    return HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
        model_name=model_name,
        model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
        encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs)
    
hf=make_embedder()

db=Chroma.from_documents(csv_data,hf,persist_directory=persist_directory)

langchain.debug = True
document_content_description = "Reported information on political violence, demonstrations (rioting and protesting), and other select non-violent, politically import events."
retriever=SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(
    OpenAI(temperature=0.1),
    db,
    document_content_description,
    metadata_field_info,
    verbose=True)
```

And this is the relevant portion of the debug log:

```
User Query:\nReturn any protests involving mine workers that occurred in Tehran in June 2023\n\nStructured Request:"
  ]
}
[llm/end] [1:retriever:Retriever > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 4:llm:OpenAI] [1.86s] Exiting LLM run with output:
{
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": "'''json\n{\n    \"query\": \"mine workers protest\",\n    \"filter\": \"and(eq(\\\"location\\\", \\\"Tehran\\\"), eq(\\\"month_of_event\\\", \\\"Jun\\\"), eq(\\\"year\\\", 2023), eq(\\\"disorder_type\\\", \\\"demonstrations\\\"))\"\n}\n'''",
        "generation_info": {
          "finish_reason": "stop",
          "logprobs": null
        },
        "type": "Generation"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "llm_output": {
    "token_usage": {
      "prompt_tokens": 2149,
      "completion_tokens": 74,
      "total_tokens": 2223
    },
    "model_name": "text-davinci-003"
  },
  "run": null
}
[chain/start] [1:retriever:Retriever > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 5:parser:StructuredQueryOutputParser] Entering Parser run with input:
{
  "input": "'''json\n{\n    \"query\": \"mine workers protest\",\n    \"filter\": \"and(eq(\\\"location\\\", \\\"Tehran\\\"), eq(\\\"month_of_event\\\", \\\"Jun\\\"), eq(\\\"year\\\", 2023), eq(\\\"disorder_type\\\", \\\"demonstrations\\\"))\"\n}\n'''"
}
[chain/end] [1:retriever:Retriever > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 5:parser:StructuredQueryOutputParser] [3ms] Exiting Parser run with output:
{
  "lc": 1,
  "type": "not_implemented",
  "id": [
    "langchain",
    "chains",
    "query_constructor",
    "ir",
    "StructuredQuery"
  ],
  "repr": "StructuredQuery(query='mine workers protest', filter=Operation(operator=<Operator.AND: 'and'>, arguments=[Comparison(comparator=<Comparator.EQ: 'eq'>, attribute='location', value='Tehran'), Comparison(comparator=<Comparator.EQ: 'eq'>, attribute='month_of_event', value='Jun'), Comparison(comparator=<Comparator.EQ: 'eq'>, attribute='year', value=2023), Comparison(comparator=<Comparator.EQ: 'eq'>, attribute='disorder_type', value='demonstrations')]), limit=None)"
}
[chain/end] [1:retriever:Retriever > 2:chain:RunnableSequence] [1.87s] Exiting Chain run with output:
[outputs]
```

Despite there being multiple documents that specifically reference mine workers protesting in Tehran, *and* those documents being returned with the similarity_search, nothing gets returned from this query.  Please advise.

Comment: Hi! did you make any progress on this? I am experiencinga similar issue, the structured query is apparently well formed, but the retrieved results do not respect the filters...

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I eventually realized this was an issue of case sensitivity; in the metadata fields, the term demonstrations was always capitalized, but the LLM created a filter for demonstrations in all lowercase.  The solution for me was to make the metadata lowercase, but this is only a partial solution as some fields should probably remain capitalized (proper names) but the model wouldn't know that.  This is something to keep an eye out for... (another issue I faced was type mismatches, where I was copying/pasting metadata entry fields and forgot to make Year an integer instead of a string.)